# How do I send a list to the jsp that requested it?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jsp-tags

Let us suppose there is a `jsp` that needs to display the list of files shared shared by a particular *IP*. Client opens that `jsp` on his local server and the request is sent to a remote server to fetch the list.

`Servlet` on the server processes the request and fetches the list of files shared by that IP. Now how do the servlet send that list to the jsp page that requested it ?

```
JSP :

connection.openConnection(); // Connection sends IP as the query parameter to the 
                             // remote servlet
```

---

```
Servlet :

doGet(..parameters..) {
 list = getList(forThatIP);
 // NOW HOW DO I SEND THIS LIST ?
}
```

One method that I thought was to send the whole data as a query string to a servlet on the client side(running a server such as tomcat) and then stash that list onto some file.Later jsp can parse the file and display the data. But that doesn't seem to be a good option.

*Note: JSP is invoked when a servlet forwards after successfully sending the IP to remote servlet*

Answer (score 1):

You can use request.setAttribute() in the Servlet. Then you can use a JSP tag to retrieve the value in JSP. Investigate a bit on that.

**EDIT :**

In the Servlet doGet method, you can set the an attribute, say listOfFiles as:

```
resquest.setAttribute("listOfFiles",list);
```

Then in the JSP you can retirieve it using the EL expression:

```
${listOfFiles}
```

which is an inbuilt feature of JSP.

Alternatively, you can access it using

```
<% request.getAttribute("listOfFiles")%>
```

but it is bad to embed Java scriptlets inside JSPs.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. Can you please elaborate

Comment: How can a servlet on the remote server forward to a jsp that is somewhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing complex data (lists etc.) over a connection, you can look into using JSON or XML.  Your JSP code should be able to parse either easily with the right library.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on how the jsp is invoked.

Do you perform a post onto it ? Does the servlet perform a forward ? Or is a sendRedirect() ?

According to this there are many ways to send data to your jsp. One is using request attributes or better, using request scoped beans. One other can be posting some sort of rappresentation of your list as a post parameter (be it json, xml or some custom format of yours).

Another thing to consider is, what are you using ? JSF ? Some Spring library ? According to that there may be other better (or worse) ways to send datas.

If working with simple JSP/Servlet on a small project I'd personally go with the request.setAttribute() way, indeed this will force me to invoke the jsp via something like

```
request.setAttribute("myList", yourListObject);
request.getRequestDispatcher("yourjsp.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

then in the jsp you can:

```
<% Object myListObj = pageContext.getRequest().getAttribute("myList"); %>
```

Comment: @saplingPro in the doGet() or doPost() method of your servlet you have to choose how to invoke the jsp. The servlet can as well emit output but I think it's better to use a "forward" to a jsp (see my example above). In this way, in your JSP, you can access the attributes and perform what you need.

Comment: I didn't know we can also send attributes across servlets/jsp that are not part of the same system..I mean a servlet on one machine and the other jsp on some remote server:)

Comment: @saplingPro it all depends on how the servlet actually invokes the jsp, there are plenty ways to make'em communicate. Still I don't understand the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a servlet from code, the best way is to use an HttpServlet and mimic the browser behavior.

Passing the data in the URL is a `GET` request. Useful only with relatively small chunks of data, but the semantics look like you want ("get a bit of data"). Something like `http://myremoteserver.com/myServlet?ip=...`. You will need a proper encoding of the parameters (the Java API can handle that).

Passing the data by writting into the stream will be a `POST` request. It has no limit in the data passed to the server, but the semantics is different ("change something in the system"). You could pass your data as a parameter inside the contents written, I am not really sure how to decode that. Another alternative is using a `Servlet` (no `HttpServlet`) and just treat the raw data.

In both cases the response will be returned in the connection output stream. You can use whatever format you like (an standard one like JSON will probably be best, even that defining your own XML). In this case, a viable alternative would be filenames separated by a 'safe' character (like `\n` or `|`). Quick, but it will be less flexible in the future.

I would go for a `GET` request and `JSON encoding`.